# What are the downsides to storing state in an append only structure on the node's disk drive somewhere?

Tags: state

In a substrate chain (not a parachain) it has been suggested to store chain data not on-chain in the paritydb, but manually saving to disk via an append only file structure (presumably using some host function calls).

What kind of substrate assumptions would this invalidate?

(To be clear I'm not advocating this, but would like some specific talking points around why this may be a sub-optimal decision)